# How daemon/parent processes manage their child processes when the parent process dies?

Tags: c++, multiprocessing, daemon

I'm creating a long-running application that will leverage child processes to do some work concurrently.  Most of the time, one can issue a signal to shutdown the server gracefully.  However, it may, at some point, be killed unexpectedly.

My question is how do daemons manage child processes when the parent/daemon dies.

I imagine the trick is all about how you set the UID/GID for the daemon so that you can kill processes by that GID or UID.

Is that right?

Comment: Sounds like orphaned processes. On just about any Unix system, these are "adopted" by init, which is (just about always) process 1.

Comment: So, do they just stick around, die at some point, or die immediately?

Comment: They keep running. In fact, this is exactly how a daemon itself works.  Wiki has a small writeup on this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orphan_process

Comment: Should the orphaned processes be cleaned up by the init.d management script, then?